# python - capture mouse input from user

Tags: python

Recently, I started working on a small user interact program, which collects user mouse click and does some action. I wonder how I can treat mouse as a device, alongside QT, and capture its left, right and middle click, and wrap up into this class.

```
class UserInputProcessor:
@abc.abstractmethod
def process_user_input(self):
    pass
```

Here is what I did for a speech recognition for macrophone:

```
class SpeechProcessor(UserInputProcessor):
def __init__(self, json_file_path = "speech_processor.json", credentials = ".credentials.json"):

        """set up microphone """
        self.process = True

def process_user_input(self):
    with self.__microphone as source:
        while self.process:
            # Continuously wait for user input
            self.__speech_converter_params["audio_data"] = None
            while self.__speech_converter_params["audio_data"] == None:
                try:
                    self.__speech_converter_params["audio_data"] = self.__recognizer.listen(
                        source,
                        phrase_time_limit = self.__config["phrase_time_limit"],
                        timeout = self.__config["timeout"])
                except sr.WaitTimeoutError:
                    print("Timing out...")
                    yield self.__speech_converter_params["audio_data"]

            # Process user speech with ASR
            str = self.__speech_converter(**self.__speech_converter_params)
            yield str
```

Comment: What does the code you have to do with your question have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found for mouse input

```
selector = selectors.DefaultSelector()

mouse = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event16')
keybd = evdev.InputDevice('/dev/input/event11')

# This works because InputDevice has a `fileno()` method.
selector.register(mouse, selectors.EVENT_READ)
selector.register(keybd, selectors.EVENT_READ)

while True:
    for key, mask in selector.select():
        device = key.fileobj
        for event in device.read():
            if event.value == 589825:
                print ("left button")
            elif event.value == 589827:
                print ("middle button")
            elif event.value == 589826:
                print ("right button")
```